# Sql Server: Select String array of JSON

Tags: json, sql-server

Given the following test data:

```
declare @mg nvarchar(max);
set @mg = '{"fiskepind":["ko","hest","gris"]}';

select @mg, JSON_VALUE(@mg,'$.fiskepind')
```

How do i get returned a column with:

```
   ko,hest,gris
```

Example returns: `NULL`, and i dont want to [index] to only get one returned.

Comment: Return each value as a dataset and then (string) aggregate.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from SQL Server 2017, a possible solution is a combination of `OPENJSON()` and `STRING_AGG()`.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG([value], ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key])) AS Result
FROM OPENJSON(@mg, '$.fiskepind')
```

Note, that `JSON_VALUE()` returns a scalar value, so the `NULL` value is the expected result when you try to extract a JSON array (`'$.fiskepind'`) from the input JSON text.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a combine list, you can use `OPENJSON` to get a table and then use `FOR XML PATH` or `STRING_AGG` to combine into a single string.

```
declare @mg nvarchar(max);
set @mg = '{"fiskepind":["ko","hest","gris"]}';

select @mg, JSON_VALUE(@mg,'$.fiskepind')
  , STUFF((
    SELECT
      ',' + value
    FROM OPENJSON(@mg, '$.fiskepind')
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ),1,1,'') as combined_list
```